# Angular ui-router render different component based on route params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-components

Using Angular UI Router, I'm trying to render a different component based on a `$state.params` value, but I can't find a clean way to do this.

I figured out a working solution already (with some ES2015 fanciness), but that's far from optimal:

```
/* ----- chapter/chapter.controller.js ----- */
class ChapterController {

  constructor($state) {
    this.$state = $state;
    this.chapterNb = this.$state.params.chapterNb;
  }

}

ChapterController.$inject = ['$state'];

export default ChapterController;

/* ----- chapter/chapter.controller.js ----- */
import controller from './chapter.controller';

const ChapterComponent = {
  controller,
  template: `
    <chapter-01 ng-if="$ctrl.chapterNb === 1"></chapter-01>
    <chapter-02 ng-if="$ctrl.chapterNb === 2"></chapter-02>
  ` // and more chapters to come...
};

export default ChapterComponent;

/* ----- chapter/index.js ----- */
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import ChaptersComponent from './chapters.component';
import ChaptersMenu from './chapters-menu';
import Chapter from './chapter';

const chapters = angular
  .module('chapters', [
    uiRouter,
    ChaptersMenu,
    Chapter
  ])
  .component('chapters', ChaptersComponent)
  .config($stateProvider => {
    'ngInject';
    $stateProvider
      .state('chapters', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/chapters',
        component: 'chapters'
      })
      .state('chapters.menu', {
        url: '/menu',
        component: 'chaptersMenu'
      })
      .state('chapters.chapter', {
        url: '/{chapterNb:int}',
        component: 'chapter'
      });
  })
  .name;

export default chapters;
```

The thing is that every `<chapter-0*>` component is very different, that's why they all correspond to their own template.
I would like to find a way to reference automatically the chapter component corresponding to the `$state.params.chapterNb` instead of having to write those `ng-if` for each one.

Is there any way to simplify this? Or maybe there is a specific feature for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Pankaj Parkar in his answer, using a template function helps here.

With a few tweaks, I've been able to achieve loading the correct component based on `$state.params`, so here is my solution, for the record (look at first post for others files involved):

```
import controller from './chapter.controller';

const ChapterComponent = {
  controller,
  template: ($state) => {
    'ngInject';
    return `
      <chapter-0${$state.params.chapterNb}></chapter-0${$state.params.chapterNb}>
    `;
  }
};

export default ChapterComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like below, if you aren't passing any data to component.

```
const ChapterComponent = {
  controller,
  template: ($state) => {
     return ['<chapter-', $state.chapterNb, '></chapter-', $state.chapterNb, '>'].join("")
  }
};
```

---

Other way is you could maintain separate template for each `chapter` & have some URL convention. Thereafter you could render those template using either `templateUrl` function of `component` or `ng-include` directive with `src`.

Comment: @ClementParis016 does it helped you?

Comment: Hey sorry I was working on something else, but yes, your help was pretty useful, thank you! I'm going to post the working solution as an answer ;)

Comment: @ClementParis016 the thing which you are using is just tweak in string concatenation, as you are using `interpolation` in template, thats it, Thanks :)